# Creating Form From two or Three Model for updating data In Yii Frontend Application

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

As i am new too yii2  i am getting confused, how should i go with.
I want a to create a form in yii2 frontend application.So do i need to create crud for it using gii or just a controller and single view  is enough.

Comment: This strongly depends on what you want to do with your form. CRUD stands for Create, Read, Update, Delete and is often used in combination with ActiveRecord. Gii is "just" a helper to create the code for everything to get started. But to learn how Yii works I recommend the documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html and writing code from the scratch.

Comment: For me is always better start with gii .. .. is a useful scaffoldind for the main action .. (and work .. )  .. the you can start from the gii result and extend your depending waht you need..

Answer (score 1):

One controller and single view enough for creating a form from multiple models, Let say A, B and C. Also from gii you need to generate only Models from table A, B and C (if has associate db table or just view model?)

on your controller actionCreate

```
$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$c = new C;

if (
$a->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && 
$b->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&
$c->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
) {
   $a->save();
   $b->save();
   $c->save();
}
$this->render('form', array('a' => $a, 'b'=>$b, 'c'=>$c));
```

And in your form view bind like this

```
 <?= $form->field($a, 'name') ?> 
 <?= $form->field($b, 'name') ?> 
 <?= $form->field($c, 'name') ?>
```

Similarly your can manage update and delete as well.

Here is an example of getting data from multiple models

> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Syed Ekram Uddin Emon. The example you gave help me a lot.